# UIPageViewController and transparent page backs

Tags: ios8, transparency, uipageviewcontroller, page-curl

Can anyone help with a problem with UIPageViewController giving transparent page backs?

I have a project displaying mock-ups of old newspapers. I am setting double sided to true and have slightly blurred and mirrored images for the page backs.

One prototype version is okay and looks like this as a page turns:

[image]

However, an updated version with different background looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the curled page back is now completely transparent.

I think the code is the same in each case although the UIView hierarchy is different.

Can anyone help me out by explaining what might be the cause?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears to be due to the fact that I had a `sublayertransform` in place that was not the Identity matrix. Resetting before using `UIPageViewController` fixes it.

`let noPerspective = CATransform3DIdentity
self.view.layer.sublayerTransform = self.noPerspective`

This clearly interfered with `UIPageViewController`'s animation.